# Uploading multiple files with properties as a child Object in .Net Core API and test in Swagger

Tags: api, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, iformfile

I am trying to implement one to many relationship-- 1 product to multiple images save method in API using .Net core(2.2) but when i try using IFormFile in child object its not showing for me an option to upload in swagger UI.

I have included IformFile in my child class but when i load swagger UI it shows as json.

```
Public Class ProductDTO{
public string Title { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public  IList<ImagesDTO> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ImagesDTO
    {
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string ImageType { get; set; }
        public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }
        public int ImageOrder { get; set; }
    }

 Save([FromForm]ProductDTO product)
```

I would like to upload multiple images for a product with image properties and would like to know can this be provided in swagger UI.